# Get MAC address in the file system

Tags: windows, macos, registry

I want to get MAC address from File system, or Registry on Windows. Because I only have image file, so I can't use WIN API to get Network Adaptor information!

So the following method maybe not work in this scenario:

```bash
ipconfig
getmac -v
GetAdaptersInfo()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the command console?the question needs more information

```
ipconfig/all
```